# Condition for $g(-x)$ to be a solution of $kf_{xx} + V(x)f(x) = cf(x)$ if $g(x)$ is a solution?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If $g(x)$ is a solution of the differential equation:- $$kf_{xx} + V(x)f(x) = cf(x)$$ 
where $k$ and $c$ are constants and $k$ is negative.

Is it necessary for $V(x)$ to be even if $g(-x)$ is also to be a solution of the mentioned differential equation?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Rearange this equation to get:

$$ V(x) = \frac{- k g_{xx}(x) + c g(x) }{g(x)}  $$

But we also have:

$$ V(x) = \frac{- k g_{xx}(-x) + c g(-x) }{g(-x)} $$

Or equivalently (using $\partial_{xx}(g(-x)) = (-1)^2 g_{xx}|_{-x} $):

$$ V(-x) = \frac{- k g_{xx}(x) + c g(x) }{g(x)} $$

Finally getting:

$$ V(x) = V(-x) $$